# Class method not recognised in php in Yii

Tags: php, function, object, yii

I have a simple model which adds 2 numbers which are gives as argument however it looks as if the build-in function add() is not getting recognised.

Here is the model

```
    <?php


class SimpleMaths extends CModel{

    private $numberone;
    private $numbertwo;


    public function SimpleMaths($numberones,$numbertwos){
        $numberone = $numberones;
        $numbertwo = $numbertwos;

    }

    public function add()
    {
        return $numbertwo + $numberone;
    }

    public function attributeNames(){
        return array('number 1' => $numberone, 'number 2'=> $numbertwo);
    }
}


?>
```

Here is the controller:

```
    <?php


class BlogController extends Controller{

    public function actionIndex(){
        $none = $_GET['n1'];
        $ntwo = $_GET['n2'];
        $model = new SimpleMaths($ntwo,$none);
        // $sum = $model.add();
        $array = get_class_methods('SimpleMaths');

        $this->render("index",array("interesting"=>$array,"model"=>$model));
    }



}



?>
```

Here is the view

```
    <?php

echo "Hello World";
foreach($interesting as $one)
{
    echo $one."<br>";
    echo "<hr>";
    echo $model.add();
}

?>
```

The add function gets displayed as one of the functions however when called it simply hides itself?

Here is the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function add() in C:\wamp\www\testdrive\protected\views\blog\index.php on line 8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the code that you are showing, it's like you want to `echo` `$model` which is an **Object**, then append whatever function `add()` returns to it,

you need to change that to

```
echo $model->add();
```

Comment: god. Php method calling. Ok.